# PHP & MySql Join Repeat the value

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables

> ```
> (1) Table Names
>       (1) id
>       (2) name
>
> (2) Table Numbers
>     (1) id
>     (2) userid
>     (3) number
> ```
>
> the query :

```
$GrabNumbers = mysql_query("SELECT name,number FROM Names
JOIN Numbers ON 
Numbers.useid = name.id");
```

when i'm joinin the tables it repeat the name like :

> john : +1 508 078 1540
>   john : +1 087 540 4508

what i need is :

```
 john : +1 508 078 1540
      : +1 087 540 4508
```

Comment: thats exactly what its supposed to do!

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is what MySQL does. If you don't want them repeated in the output, you'll need to create a PHP script to output them properly.

Something like this:

```
$printed = array();
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
  if( isset ( $printed[ $row['name'] ] ) ) {
    // print only the number
  }
  else {
    // print both number and name

    // then, add the name to the list of names already printed
    $printed[$row['name']] = true;
  }
}
```

And make sure you order the rows by the name! Otherwise you might get unpredictable (and wrong) results.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function grouping by `name` column like below. (SQL only answer; No idea about PHP)

```
select n.name,
group_concat(distinct nu.numbers SEPARATOR ':')
FROM `Names` n
JOIN `Numbers` nu ON 
nu.userid = n.id
group by n.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$GrabNumbers = mysql_query("SELECT name,number FROM Names
JOIN Numbers ON 
Numbers.useid = name.id");
$name = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GrabNumbers)){
   if($name == '' OR $name != $row['name']){
      echo $row['name'] . ' : ' . $row['number'];
   }
   else{
       echo ' : ' . $row['number'];
   }
    $name = $row['name'];
}
```